# What is alternative way to do `Ctrl + 0` and `Ctrl + 9` in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I watched some Inkscape tutorials, and came across a wonderful feature in Inkscape to quickly change thickness of a path or an object by hitting `CTRL + 0` and `CTRL + 9`. But I've searched all over the internet, searched in `Preferences -> Interface -> Keyboard Shortcuts` and I haven't found anything regarding this feature.

From my understanding, these shortcuts make the object bolder or thinner by approximately 1 pixel. But in some cases, I'd really love to change the step value of this operation, so instead of making object 1 pixel bolder, I make it 0.5 pixel bolder.

So my question is, how is this feature called, and how do I adjust the value which used to perform the transformation.

Comment: idk Inkscape at all, but often this type of feature can be *10 by holding Shift or Alt at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcuts you seem to be talking about are for Outset <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd> and Inset <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd>, which also happen to be located on the <kbd>9</kbd> and <kbd>0</kbd> keys. Outset and Inset can also be found under the Path menu item in the main menu along the top.  You need to have a path or object selected for it to work.